# How do I setup simple firebase ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, firebase

I know I can use set to hit Firebase, but I want to use AJAX instead so I tried the below code. When I load test.html in my browser, the console says -

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://jleiphonebook.firebaseio.com/json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.**

//text.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Firebase Test</title>
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="hi"></div>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"   integrity="sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        var param = {lastName: "Doe", firstName: "John"};
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://jleiphonebook.firebaseio.com/json',
          type: "POST",
          data: param,
          success: function () {
            alert("success");
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

//firebase rules

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `.` before `json`, so `https://jleiphonebook.firebaseio.com/.json`.

Comment: Given that you're loading loading JSON data, you'll probably want to use `$.getJSON()`:

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added the . and it got a bad request feedback. I'm making a POST request, can you explain why I should use getJSON? that didn't work either

Comment: Ah, I missed that you're trying to add data. In that case indeed, you can't use `getJSON()`. You'll still need the `.` in there though. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/saving-data.html#section-post for an example of how to POST with curl, you'll need to do the equivalent in jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase expects the body to be a JSON string, so you'll need to stringify it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var param = {lastName: "Doe", firstName: "John"};

   $.ajax({
     url: 'https://jleiphonebook.firebaseio.com/.json',
     type: "POST",
     data: JSON.stringify(param),
     success: function () {
       alert("success");
     },
     error: function(error) {
       alert("error: "+error);
     }
   });
 });
```

This will accomplish the same by the way:

```
$.post('https://jleiphonebook.firebaseio.com/.json',
  JSON.stringify(param),
  function () {
    alert("success");
  }
);
```

Comment: awesome thanks! I didn't see this in any of the docs, can you refer to where they stated this? I'd like to understand how to un-stringify this when I get the information back